# How can I call a jQuery function after my model data has been updated?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple function that loads data into `{{my_content}}`. The problem is that I want to execute a jQuery script `myJqueryFunction()` after `{{my_content}}` has been updated. The code below works except that `myJqueryFunction()` seems to be called before (or not at all?) `{{my_content}}` had been updated. Any suggestions?

```
$scope.showContent = function(){
    $http({
        url: "my/url",
        method: "POST"
    })
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
        $scope.my_content = data; 
        myJqueryFunction();
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { $scope.status = status; });
};
```

Comment: There's no reason this won't work so long as the success handler fires.  If you can make a Plunkr or JSFiddle to show the issue I'll take a look but as is I see no reason the function wouldn't be called every time the success handler is triggered.

Comment: It's called, I think, but it needs to be called AFTER ``{{my_content}}`` has been updated. How can I ensure that it is called only after ``{{my_content}}`` is updated?

Comment: I found a good article on $scope.$apply() that explains a bit more than I knew about how it works: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html But it really depends on what you expect the jQuery function to be able to do in response to the angular change.  For example if it is reading information computed by the browser then that data may not be updated yet, you may have to instead use a $timeout as suggested which just does the same as setTimeout in javascript but also calls $scope.$apply automatically (or listen for specific browser events about CSS being applied etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$timeout` to guarantee that such function is executed in a subsequent apply-digest cycle.

```
$timeout(function () {
    myJqueryFunction();
})
```

**Updated:**  certainly you'll have to inject `$timeout` into the controller, by adding `$timeout` to your controller's arguments (perhaps you need to specifically state `'$timeout'` in the injector array as well, depending on your choice of injection approach.)